# Why is client.video not defined while creating a room using twilio rest API?

Tags: node.js, express, twilio

I am trying to create a room using the twilio rest api so that I can attach a statusCallback url to listen to room events. I am using the same code given in the docs:

```
var apiKeySid = 'SKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var apiKeySecret = 'your_api_key_secret';
var accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var Twilio = require('twilio');

var client = new Twilio(apiKeySid, apiKeySecret, {accountSid: accountSid});

classroomRouter.route('/room/:id')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        console.log(client);

        client.video.rooms
            .create({
                uniqueName: req.params.id,
                statusCallback: 'localhost:3000/classrooms/listen'
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It somehow worked when I updated my twilio node helper library from 3.0.0 to 3.6.7.

Comment: `video` was only added to Twilio Node from version 3.1.0 and upwards. :)